# Using the Jena RDF library, how do I return the property of a URI resource?

Tags: rdf, jena

I have a Jena URI Resource (*Resource* reference to an object where *isURIResource()* returns true). An example Resource URI is this:

> http://d.opencalais.com/er/company/ralg-tr1r/4ee13d20-b44f-3bce-98bc-49a303e72db5

If you open that in a web browser, you'll probably be given the HTML representation of the data:

> http://d.opencalais.com/er/company/ralg-tr1r/4ee13d20-b44f-3bce-98bc-49a303e72db5.html

You can change the **.html** extension to **.rdf** giving you:

> http://d.opencalais.com/er/company/ralg-tr1r/4ee13d20-b44f-3bce-98bc-49a303e72db5.rdf

This RDF model is formatted as XML. The property I need to retrieve is:

```
<c:symbol>MSFT.OQ</c:symbol>
```

In summary, I'm looking for a way to use my Jena URI Resource to return the value of **c:symbol**, which in my example would be **MSFT.OQ**

I'm aware that I could take this URI, GET the RDF representation via some HTTP client, then load and query the model as I'm doing already. What I'm assuming, however, is that Jena offers a more elegant solution to this recurring task.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Jena URI Resource"? Jena is a Java program library used for managing RDF and OWL through a programmatic API. Is this a URI expopsed when running a Jena application?

Comment: Yes, this URI is exposed while running the application. As I mentioned, you can even visit the URI right now in your browser. When I say "Jena URI Resource" I mean I am using the Jena library to query a model and traverse the result set. Some of my results are literals, while one is a Resource. This Resource has a URI which points to another RDF model (given above in the URI) which contains the data I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Jena has a 'streaming' API just like the StaX API for XML. Might help: last year, I wrote a *simple*  streaming parser for RDF: [A lightweight java parser for RDF](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2009/03/lightweight-java-parser-for-rdf.html). It does not handle the full RDF spec, but you might get some ideas there.